# Adding a triangle icon inside a button for users to know that this button has a drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, button, geometry

I'm still learning HTML and CSS and right now i'm playing around on a simple button, you can view the demo of the button [here.](http://cssdeck.com/labs/kl2deulh).

As you can see the triangle icon is positioned at the bottom of the button in the demo. I want to make it position on the right side the button for users to know that this button has a drop down menu

Is there any way I can position the triangle icon on the right side with this code below?

HTML:

```
<a class="language-icon" href="#" alt="Choose your language">Language: <span>English<span>
 <div class="arrow-up"></div>
 <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
    .language-icon {
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      color: #202020;
      padding-right: 8px;
      padding-left: 27px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 11px;  
      width: auto;
      text-align: right;
      text-decoration: none;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
      background: #f8f8f8 url("images/language-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0 ;
    }

    .language-icon span {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .language-icon:hover { 
      background: #fff url("images/language-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 -20px ; 
      color: #d13030;
      border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #e5e5e5;
     }

    .arrow-down {
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      border-right: 5px solid transparent;  
      border-top: 5px solid #202020;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by giving the following styles to your `language-icon` anchor class:

```
position: relative;
top: 0; left: 0; /* Important for some browsers */
```

And then styling your arrow thus:

```
.arrow-down{
    /*...*/
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 45%;
    /*...*/
}
```

`position:absolute` will bind to the nearest ancestor with non-static positioning (hence `position:relative` above). Make sure you give `.language-icon` enough right padding to accommodate.

[Updated example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/ysdop354/)

Comment: Exactly how I wanted the button to be. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend giving `.language-icon` a fixed with and height

```
width: 110px;
height: 30px;
```

Add this to `.down-arrow`

```
position: relative;
right:-4px;
top:5px;
float: right;
```

And change the divs to spans.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/pk1qwjhi

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS property:

```
display:inline;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to change the css as below

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;  
    border-top: 5px solid #202020;    
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-left:5px;
  }
```

And changes the html as below

```
<a class="language-icon" href="#" alt="Choose your language"> 
  <div class="arrow-up"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  Language: <span>English<span>
</a>
```

That gives me a display you wanted.

But generally it's not a good idea to wrap *div* inside *a*, you might pay attention to the new added *display: inline-block;* in the css definition, this defines the div to be displayed in the same line as the text and is the key point here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to play with the position attributr in CSS

```
.language-icon {
position:relative;
border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
color: #202020;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-left: 27px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 11px;  
width: auto;
text-align: right;
text-decoration: none;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
background: #f8f8f8 url("http://placehold.it/30x30") no-repeat 0 0 ;
}

.arrow-down {
 width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;  
border-top: 5px solid #202020;
position:absolute;
top:5px;
right:0%;
```

}